# October CMS | Throw AJAX exception with translated message

Tags: octobercms

According to the documentation ([here](https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/handlers#throw-ajax-exception)) I can throw AJAX exception by using the following code:

```
throw new AjaxException([
    'error' => 'Not enough questions',
    'questionsNeeded' => 2
]);
```

But my website is multilingual, so I need to return translated messages, how I can create those messages and return them according to the selected language?

Or there are onother GOOD practices to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can refer to the localization options on the Documentation

https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/localization

It's a nice way to handle that things